# Reveal unique code to each person who likes a 'fan gate' on facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I'm looking in to the idea of revealing a unique code to every person who clicks like on a facebook fangate page, the code would be for a voucher redeemable outside of facebook, and must be unique for each person.

I've gotten as far as revealing content when a user likes the tab, what I was hoping to do is check the person's facebook ID against a database, then if then if they haven't already been given a code, assign their user id to a code and reveal the code.

I guess the real question I'm asking is, can I get a user's unique facebook ID once they click like in application tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: No

But you can ask for basic permissions. 
Additionally it's against facebook rules to use fangate as only restriction for participation. You can implement the folowing user journey:

1. Fan gate
2. Once user likes your page provide a button "Get your code"
3. Upon clicking the button ask for bassic permissions.
4. After the redirect fetch the user id check it against the DB if he already got a code.
5. If above is false write the user id into the table.
6. get user code and display it.

This way you will give the ability to user to see the code again if he lost it.